# What was the point of releasing the President's 'unofficial schedule' in S1E13?

Tags: plot-explanation, house-of-cards

What was the point of releasing the President's 'unofficial schedule' in *House of Cards* S1E13? Is it to hurt the public support for Tusk when he is announced as VP?

Answer (score 2):

Before releasing the President schedule, when Linda tells Frank that President Walker will have a meeting with Tusk in a few days, Franks asks Linda to arrange a meeting between the President and the Speaker of the House, Bob Birch.

Only one secret meeting with Raymond Tusk would maybe go unnoticed. But the fact that the President meets these two men in two different days, plus the fact that Jim Matthews runs for the office of Governor of California (hence resigning from VP's office), plus the fact that the schedule his secret makes Slugline write that the President is interviewing possible candidates for Vice-Presidency.

This makes the press going haywire and concerned people make unprecautious moves (including Remy revealing he works for Tusk).